# Divisors of a "symmetric" polynomial

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, ring-theory, multivariate-polynomial

Let $k$ be a field. Let $F$ be a polynomial in $k[x_{1},\ldots,x_{n},y_{1},\ldots,y_{n}]$ with the following "symmetric" property (S):

If we write $F$ explicitly as $\displaystyle F=\sum_{i} c_{i} (\prod_{j_{i}} x_{j_{i}}^{p_{j_{i}}}\prod_{k_{i}}y_{k_{i}}^{q_{k_{i}}})$, $c_{i}$ constant and $p_{j_{i}},q_{k_{i}}$ positive integers. Then $p_{j_{i}}=q_{k_{i}}$ if $j_{i}=k_{i}$ (in other word, this means that inside each summand, $x$'s and $y$'s with same indices appear in pairs).

I am guessing if I have a nontrivial divisor of this $F$, it should also satisfy property (S), but not quite sure. Also failed to find any counterexample.

Any comments, hint towards proof or a counterexample is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Let's do a simple case first: can you do it for $n=1$, i.e., $F\in k[x,y]$?

Comment: ok, I see a counterexample. let $T$ be something have (S). Then $(x^{2}y^{3}+T)(x^{2}y-T/y^{2})$ will do.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but isn't the factorization $xy=x\cdot y$ already a counterexample? Then again I also don't understand how your comment provides a counterexample, as the product is
$$x^4y^4+(T/y)^2,$$
which doesn't have $x$ and $y$ appear in pairs if $T$ does.